# Why doesn't Walt tell Walt Jr the truth about Hank?

Tags: breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad*, Walt wouldn't want his son to know he was a killer at all but especially not to think he killed his uncle.  Why didn't Walt say in Ozymandias (S5/14) the Nazi gang killed Hank whenever Skyler is asking him where Hank is?

I know Walt alluded to Skyler on the phone that he killed Hank to sound even more dangerous and he told her in Felina that some men killed him but Walt Jr will still think his Dad murdered his uncle.

Comment: Duplicate? http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24784/49

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson Agree, it's the same question.

Comment: I don't know for sure (which is why I didn't just close it single-handedly, but just put it up for consideration). One concentrates on Skyler and the other one seems to say *"I know why he didn't tell it Skyler, but why not Flynn?"*.

Comment: This seems different enough to remain. The psychology differs between family members.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Feel free to reopen-vote then.

Answer (score 3):

I think, he will get the whole story told by Skyler after the show had ended.

When Walt visited Skyler in the last episode, he was watched by the police, etc. and he had to fight against Jack and his men! Walt cannot risk at that point to be found.

Walt Jr. has proven himself to be not trustworthy to keep a secret this big. In order to convince him about the truth about Hank, someone must tell him that Walt was here to tell his. When Walt phones Walt Jr. in S05E15, Walt Jr. was screaming around in the school, etc. He knows that if he or Skyler told Walt Jr. about Hank, his plan could not work. For example, if they would *only* go to the police, Jack and his men would probably get revenge on Walt's family, or they would be prepared of seeing Walt.

Skyler seems to have trust in Walt (e.g., she was not telling that he was there), so she let him do his work. After the series ended, she would get called to the Nazi clubhouse and can also see that Todd and the others who threaten her were dead. Plus, she can trade the coordinates of Hank's "grave". At that point, the old story about Walt does not make that much sense and Walt Jr. is maybe willing to hear (and accept) the truth.

Comment: It was necessary to sacrifice his reputation with his son, in order to protect his family. Make Walt Jr. believe he had killed Hank, when in reality the Nazis had done it. In this way, Walt Jr's anger would be directed away from the danger. Then when Skyler saw that Walt was dead (surely later they Id'd his body at the compound and told her), then, like you said, she thought "ok, it's time to tell him." and revealed to Jr. the truth.